# Loop repeats itself before complete

Tags: c, loops

I'm trying to write a data text with c but something is wrong with process order. Loop repeats itself before complete. It have to 'yes or no' but it prints 'go' after ask and later scanf process. What is wrong in that code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    FILE *potr;

    char go = 'e',name[20],sname[20];
    int age;

    potr = fopen("example.txt","w");

    if(potr == NULL) printf("File cannot open");

    while(go != 'n'){
        printf("go\n");
        scanf("%s %s %d",name,sname,&age);
        fprintf(potr,"%s %s %d",name,sname,age);
        printf("\ny or n :");
        scanf("%c",&go);
    }

    fclose(potr);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly `fopen()` error handling is not correct, this

```
potr = fopen("example.txt","w");
if(potr == NULL) 
printf("File cannot open"); /* doesn't make any sense */
```

should be

```
potr = fopen("example.txt","w");
if(potr == NULL) {
    printf("File cannot open");
    return 0; /* return if open failed */
}
```

secondly, use

```
scanf(" %c",&go); /* To avoid buffering issue i.e after char you pressed ENTER i.e 2 input. space before %c will work */
```

instead of

```
scanf("%c",&go);
```

Sample code :

```
int main(void){
        FILE *potr = fopen("example.txt","w");
        if(potr == NULL){
                 printf("File cannot open");
                return 0;
        }
        char go = 'e',name[20],sname[20];
        int age;

        while(go != 'n'){
                printf("go\n");
                scanf("%19s%19s%d",name,sname,&age);
                fprintf(potr,"%s %s %d",name,sname,age);
                printf("\ny or n :");
                scanf(" %c",&go); /* whitespace before %c */
        }
        fclose(potr);
        return 0;
}
```

Also in this particular case you can use `do..while` instead of `while` as first time you want to enter into loop irrespective of condition is true or false by assigning `go` as `e`. For e.g

```
do{
        printf("go\n");
        scanf("%19s%19s%d",name,sname,&age);
        fprintf(potr,"%s %s %d",name,sname,age);
        printf("\ny or n :");
        scanf(" %c",&go); /* whitespace before %c */
}while(go == 'y' || go == 'Y');
```